# Redondear numero de 8.6 a 8.5 utilizando SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Hola buenas tardes a todos.

Tengo un problema cuando intento redondear unas calificaciones utilizando SQL SERVER.

Les anexo unos ejemplos:

***Necesito redondear 8.6 a 8.5 (de 8.9 a 8.5 se queda en 8.5)***

> Intento

```
SELECT ROUND(8.6, 1, 1) AS resultado;
```

> Resultado (No me esta redondeando)

**8.6**

***Otro ejemplo es redondear de 8.1 a 8.0 (de 8.4 a 8.0 se queda en 8.0)***

> Intento

```
SELECT ROUND(8.1, 1, 1) AS resultado;
```

> Resultado (No me esta redondeando)

**8.1**

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos y que tengan un excelente miércoles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No **creo** exista una función que haga EXACTAMENTE lo que pides. Al menos no una "built in Function". Pero...

Si quieres ponerte creativo, puedes hacer algo así:

1. La funcion [`parsename(Calificacion,1)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) te devuelve la parte derecha del número, es decir la parte decimal. Esto es lo que queremos evaluar, correcto?
2. Hacemos un condicional donde, de acuerdo a tus parametros, si la parte decimal está entre cinco y nueve (incluyéndolos), entonces, se concatena la parte entera del número  y  '.5' . Si si la parte decimal está entre cero y cuatro(incluyéndolos), entonces, se concatena la parte entera del número y  '.0'

Puedes correr este código en tu SSMS y funcionará en sqlServer 2016 y posteriores.

```
     Drop table if exists #numbers
     CREATE TABLE #Numbers (Calificacion DECIMAL(16, 1));
     INSERT INTO #Numbers (Calificacion)
     VALUES (8.6);
     INSERT INTO #Numbers (Calificacion)
     VALUES( 8.4);
     INSERT INTO #Numbers (Calificacion)
     VALUES (390.7);
     INSERT INTO #Numbers (Calificacion)
     VALUES (12.7);
     INSERT INTO #Numbers (Calificacion)
     VALUES (390.1);




     SELECT     Calificacion
                    , PARSENAME(Calificacion,1) AS ParteDecimal             
                    ,Case 
                          when PARSENAME(Calificacion,1)>=5 AND PARSENAME(Calificacion,1)<=9
                          Then Concat(Parsename(Calificacion,2),'.5')   
                          When PARSENAME(Calificacion,1)>=0 AND PARSENAME(Calificacion,1)<=4
                          then Concat(Parsename(Calificacion,2),'.0')
                         end as CalificacionRedondeada
 
 FROM #NUMBERS
```

Resultado:

```
Calificacion ParteDecimal CalificacionRedondeada
-------------------------------------------------
8.6      |       6          |       8.5
8.4      |       4          |       8.0
390.7    |       7          |       390.5
12.7     |       7          |       12.5
390.1    |       1          |       390.0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ♥

Comment: Como comentario, pensé que `Between` no incluía los valores en los extremos, pero [sí lo hace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749615/does-ms-sql-servers-between-include-the-range-boundaries). Entonces, puedes utilizar únicamente `Between 5 and 9`, en el primer condicional y `between 0 and 4` en el segundo.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es redondear a valores enteros o mitades, lo más fácil es multiplicar el número por dos, truncarlo y volver a dividirlo entre dos. Se puede truncar con el tercer parámetro de `ROUND()` o usando `FLOOR()` pero la funcionalidad cambia en valores negativos.

```
 CREATE TABLE #Numbers (Calificacion DECIMAL(16, 1));
 INSERT INTO #Numbers (Calificacion)
 VALUES (8.6),
        ( 8.4),
        (390.7),
        (12.7),
        (390.1),
        (-3.4);

 SELECT Calificacion,
        CAST( ROUND( Calificacion*2,0,1)/2 AS DECIMAL(16, 1)),
        CAST( FLOOR( Calificacion*2)/2 AS DECIMAL(16, 1))
 FROM #Numbers;

 GO
 DROP TABLE #numbers;
```

Comment: Luis, buena respuesta! Nos puedes decir cómo cambia el comportamiento con valores negativos?

Comment: Por eso puse el ejemplo con el número negativo.